# Potential bug concerning kicking users that share a name

Tags: bug, status-norepro, chat

We just had a user experience difficulties speaking in the JS room -- he has spoken before, I remember him.

A user with the same name as him was kicked 3 days ago, and it *seemed* to affect this one's ability to chat.

Here is our [chat convo](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98141/room-for-martin-and-sterling-archer) to get some more info out there.

Is this a bug concerning usernames being kicked and all people with the same username being affected, or is this a one-off coincidence?

Better safe than sorry.

Comment: As mentioned in the chat, I had received notifications that were sent to @martin rather than to me. This leads me to believe that the kicking mechanism could have affected me as well

Comment: Note - it wasn't me!

Comment: @alexk So glad someone corrected that...

Comment: While we're at fixing this bug, let's remove 3 letter pings, because clearly that's more of an irritating bug than it is actually helpful...

Comment: @ndugger http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/268351/213575

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's pure coincidence. Nothing in chat (or Q&A site) code is based on user names (or display names, to be precise), except for actually looking up the person who was mentioned in a comment or chat message. Unlike on many other sites, the display name isn't used as an identifier here (which has some [fun consequences](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268351/rfc-better-chat-mentions-a-prototype)). Anything that isn't explicitly involved in parsing comments or chat messages for mentions only cares about numeric user ids.

I don't know what exactly happened here since it seems to have fixed itself, so it will probably remain a mystery.

What I can tell you with 100% certainty however (and I've been programming long enough to know that you should never do that) is that a display name similarity with a recently kicked user will never somehow cause parts the kickage to "spill over" to the other user.*

---

<sub>*unless of course a *human* makes a mistake and thinks "Hey isn't that the one that I just kicked? Why are they back? Let's kick again!" – but that's not what happened here; the Martin with Stack Overflow Chat user id 1007638 has never been kicked.</sub>

Comment: I want to believe you, but your 100% certainty is incredibly worrying.

Comment: Anytime anyone says anything with 100% certainty, there's a 50% chance they're dead wrong.